# move_uploaded_file só funciona uma vez no arquivo

Tags: php

Estou utilizando a função `move_uploaded_file`

Na primeira vez que eu a utilizo, envio um determinado vídeo para uma pasta temporária.

**1**

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cadVideo']['tmp_name'], "temporario/" . 'temp-'.$_FILES['cadVideo']['name']);
```

*Funciona perfeitamente!*

Ok! Depois disso, realizo algumas outras atribuições e funções e novamente preciso utilizar a `move_uploaded_file`. Acontece que neste segundo ponto ela não funciona mais.

**2**

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cadVideo']['tmp_name'], "../../Aulas/{$sessao[0]}/{$sessao[1]}/{$sessao[2]}/".$_FILES['cadVideo']['name']);
```

Logo de inicio pensei que poderia ser alguma erro relacionado a diretórios ou coisa parecida, então revisei e concluí que não era esse o erro. Mas mesmo assim não funcionava.

Para fins de teste copiei e colei a mesma função **(1)** e coloquei no lugar da **(2)** e para a minha surpresa também não funcionou.

Fiquei intrigado com isso, como pode uma função que funciona normalmente não funcionar novamente algumas linhas de código depois?

move_uploaded_file funciona apenas uma vez no arquivo? Se sim, como posso me esquivar deste problema?

Comment: SIm, funciona uma vez só, pq uma vez movido nao é mais uploaded file. Pra se esquivar, mova com as funções normais de arquivo do PHP, em vez de usar a específica para uploads. ou já mova para o lugar certo de uma vez só. O move_uploaded_file é praticamente uma operação apenas para "aceitar em definitivo" o upload tirando do local temporário e evitando seu descarte.

Comment: E quais são essas funções normais? Não é possível mover para o lugar certo de uma vez só, o arquivo passa por pequeno tratamento antes.

Comment: use o "move" normal mesmo (renomear a parte do diretório) http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rename.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `move_uploaded_file` é praticamente uma operação apenas para "aceitar em definitivo" o upload tirando do local temporário (geralmente o próprio TEMP ou TMP do sistema de arquivos) evitando seu descarte ao fim do *script*. Uma vez movido, ele vai ser tratado como outro arquivo qualquer pelo PHP.

Em resumo, você só usará o `move_uploaded_file` num primeiro momento.

Para mover um arquivo convencional em PHP a função é `rename`, que é adequada para o segundo passo da sua aplicação, após fazer o tratamento necessário no arquivo aceito anteriormente.

Exemplo de uso:

```
rename( "caminho1/arquivo.jpg", "caminho2/arquivo.jpg" );
```

O `rename` serve tanto para mudar o nome do arquivo em si, como o caminho deste. Para mover sem mudar o nome, basta alterar apenas a parte do caminho, e manter o final. Isto é similar ao que acontece na linha de comando dos sistemas baseados em *nix

Mais no manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rename.php

Answer (score 2):

O que ocorre neste caso é o seguinte: Quando é feito o POST enviando o arquivo pelo formulário, esse aquivo fica salvo na memória do servidor, e quando você usa a função `move_uploaded_file` ele tira o arquivo da memória e joga na pasta de destino. Por isso que quando você tenta usar pela segunda vez ele não encontra mais o arquivo na memória, pois já foi movido a um destino.

Neste caso você pode simplesmente copiar o arquivo que você já salvou em disco para um outro local usando a função `copy` do PHP, veja a documentação oficial dela aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.copy.php

Ou se quiser mover o arquivo para outro local, pode usar a função `rename` do PHP, que caso seja especificado um outro diretório ele automaticamente move o arquivo. Documentação oficial: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Comment: O copy neste caso duplica meu arquivo! E como ele é apenas um arquivo temporário existe a necessidade de ser destruído depois. Mas gostei da explicação da função! Obrigado.

Comment: Neste caso pode usar a função `rename` para mover o arquivo. Complementei na resposta